# How to increase speed for ObjectAnimator onClick method?

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator

I m trying to increase the speed (duration) for the setmButton when mButton is clicked, but no results.I need to make the mButton to move from x=0 to x=100 in less seconds so i will increase the speed. The mButon animation starts from x=0 and move to x=100 in duration=10000, when i click on it i want the mButton to increase the speed to the final position. 
Thank you

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void animationA() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            final ImageButton mButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.Button );
            assert mButton != null;
            mButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.Button);




            ObjectAnimator mButtonAnimation= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mButton , "translationX", 0, -2100);
            mButtonAnimation.setDuration(11000);
            mButtonAnimation.setStartDelay(50);
            mButtonAnimation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
            mButtonAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
            ObjectAnimator mButtonAnimation1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mButton, "alpha", 0, 1);
            mButtonAnimation1 .setDuration(90);

            mButtonAnimation1 .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
            final AnimatorSet setmButton = new AnimatorSet();
            setmButton .playTogether(mButtonAnimatiea, mButtonAnimation1 );
            //setmButton .setFillAfter(true);

            setmButton.start();






            mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {





                    Handler handlermButton = new Handler();
                    handlermButton.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                           setmButton.setDuration(500);


                        }
                    }, 100);

                }
            });



        }}, 100); }
```

Comment: `"I m trying to increase the speed (duration)"` no, speed != duration, so you want to increase speed **or** duration?

Comment: increase the speed

Answer (score 0):

You could use ACCELERATE interpolator if you want an higher speed level near from the end or simply set the duration to a lower value so the animation will be faster.

Comment: i need to increase the speed after you click the button

Comment: Are you able to setDuration on button click to a lower value ? Or I am testing scaleCurrentDuration method. I'll come back if it is a success :)

Comment: setmButton.setDuration(500); is not working, not changing the duration in animation